# Let $|X|$ be a random variable in $(\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Is it true that $X$ is also a random variable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $|X|$ be a random variable in $(\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Is it true that $X$ is also a random variable?

I tried to prove it by Borel sigma algebra defnition of an r.v., but that appeared to be a wrng proof. My guess is that an answer is "False", but I have no idea how to prove it

I guess we just need to prove that if f(x) is an r.v. and $\not \exists $ function $ f^{-1}$ and automatically our $X$ wouldn't be an r.v. since $f^{-1}$ isn't a function

Answer (score 4):

Take any non-measurable set $A\subseteq\Omega$ from the sample space, and define:

$X(\omega)=\begin{cases}
1 &: \omega \in A \\
-1 &: \omega \not\in A
\end{cases}$

This is clearly not a random variable, as $\{X=1\}$ is not measurable. But $|X|$ is just the constant function $1$, which is a random variable.

I assumed there is a non-measurable set in $\Omega$. If all the subsets of $\Omega$ are measurable then any function is a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed false. Fix the probability space $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), \gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is the standard gaussian measure. Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $X = 1_A - 1_{A^c}$. Then $|X| = 1$ is measurable but $X$ is not so that $X$ is not a random variable.